# Delete password, Last login, Superuser status, Groups, User permissions...filed in User tab in Django admin after clicking into a specific user

Tags: python, django

I have used Django2 and simpleUI to develop a Django web app.
Now I want to delete password, Last login, Superuser status, Groups, User permissions...filed in Django admin.
How could I do that? I tried to unregister my user and rewrite it, but failed to delete anything.

admin.py:

````
```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import forms
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
admin.site.register(User)
````

I have tried

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('email', 'first_name')
list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

But it did not delete any thing when I click a specific user, still shows password, Last login, Date joined,blah blah, those kind of fields that boss want me to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can register another super user and chage any thing You want

```
python maange.py createsuperuser
```

you if you want to change password of any superuser

```
python manage.py changepassword (superuser_name)
```

you can delete sqlite database and startwith fresh form migrate

Comment: I mean I wanna delete those fields in admin panel. so after login to admin panel, no password field should be seen

Comment: ur answer has no solution to my problem, as I wanna hide the password field in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Override UserAdmin.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    "Declare your custom fields or fieldset here."

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: how could I delete default fields?

Comment: how could I delete default fields like password, last login..., those kind of fields showing when click into a specific user?

Comment: By delete, you mean not showing them, don't you? If yes, look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets . You need to override fieldset, by defining the fields you want, other fields won't show up.